# How to find what an Apache httpd process is doing?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a web application that is used nearly constantly by 5 - 10 users. Between 1 and 3 times a day it will grind to a halt.

When this happens I can see the following in TOP:

```
last pid:  1744;  load averages: 15.50, 45.91, 31.79                                                        up 0+01:04:01  14:47:59
357 processes: 1 running, 351 sleeping, 5 waiting
CPU:  0.2% user,  0.0% nice,  2.8% system,  2.4% interrupt, 94.6% idle
Mem: 1612M Active, 180M Inact, 174M Wired, 8012K Cache, 103M Buf, 108K Free
Swap: 4096M Total, 2104M Used, 1992M Free, 51% Inuse, 40M Out

  PID USERNAME    THR PRI NICE   SIZE    RES STATE   C   TIME   WCPU COMMAND
 1384 www           1  44    0   156M  3256K pfault  0   0:36  0.00% httpd
 1477 www           1  44    0   154M  8008K pfault  1   0:35  0.00% httpd
 1053 mysql       161  44    0   199M 54108K umtxn   0   0:27  0.00% mysqld
 1441 www           1  44    0   154M     0K WAIT    0   0:26  0.00% <httpd>
 1521 www           1  44    0   164M     0K sbwait  1   0:20  0.00% <httpd>
 1519 www           1  44    0   156M  7832K pfault  0   0:19  0.00% httpd
 1520 www           1  44    0   138M  8724K select  1   0:19  0.00% httpd
 1527 www           1  46    0   138M     0K accept  0   0:17  0.00% <httpd>
 1422 www           1  44    0   138M  3096K pfault  0   0:16  0.00% httpd
 1290 root          1  44    0   130M  9060K select  1   0:15  0.00% httpd
 1529 www           1  44    0   164M  3740K pfault  1   0:15  0.00% httpd
 1532 www           1  44    0   154M 22704K pfault  0   0:15  0.00% httpd
 1530 www           1  44    0   164M     0K sbwait  0   0:14  0.00% <httpd>
 1525 www           1  44    0   156M     0K sbwait  1   0:14  0.00% <httpd>
 1531 www           1  44    0   138M  8168K pfault  1   0:13  0.00% httpd
 1528 www           1  44    0   164M     0K sbwait  0   0:13  0.00% <httpd>
 1533 www           1  44    0   156M  3252K pfault  1   0:12  0.00% httpd
 1534 www           1  44    0   156M  3592K pfault  1   0:12  0.00% httpd
 1544 www           1  44    0   156M  4620K pfault  1   0:12  0.00% httpd
 1540 www           1  44    0   156M  4340K pfault  1   0:12  0.00% httpd
 1543 www           1  44    0   156M  4744K pfault  0   0:11  0.00% httpd
 1546 www           1  44    0   154M 11764K pfault  1   0:11  0.00% httpd
 1547 www           1  44    0   154M  8176K pfault  0   0:11  0.00% httpd
 1545 www           1  44    0   154M  8660K pfault  1   0:11  0.00% httpd
 1541 www           1  44    0   156M     0K WAIT    1   0:10  0.00% <httpd>
 1558 www           1  44    0   158M 19996K pfault  0   0:10  0.00% httpd
 1559 www           1  44    0   154M 10324K pfault  0   0:10  0.00% httpd
 1555 www           1  44    0   154M 18796K pfault  1   0:09  0.00% httpd
 1569 www           1  44    0   156M  6208K pfault  0   0:09  0.00% httpd
 1566 www           1  44    0   154M 10996K pfault  0   0:09  0.00% httpd
 1561 www           1  44    0   156M 15724K pfault  1   0:09  0.00% httpd
 1562 www           1  44    0   154M  8076K pfault  0   0:09  0.00% httpd
 1572 www           1  44    0   154M 11308K pfault  0   0:09  0.00% httpd
 1571 www           1  44    0   154M     0K sbwait  0   0:08  0.00% <httpd>
 1553 www           1  44    0   154M     0K sbwait  1   0:08  0.00% <httpd>
 1567 www           1  44    0   154M 13108K pfault  1   0:08  0.00% httpd
 1565 www           1  44    0   152M 17284K pfault  0   0:08  0.00% httpd
 1602 www           1  44    0   156M  4232K pfault  1   0:08  0.00% httpd
 1548 www           1  44    0   154M  8948K pfault  0   0:08  0.00% httpd
 1577 www           1  44    0   156M 15732K pfault  0   0:08  0.00% httpd
 1573 www           1  44    0   156M 16244K pfault  0   0:08  0.00% httpd
 1554 www           1  44    0   154M     0K sbwait  0   0:08  0.00% <httpd>
 1585 www           1  44    0   156M     0K WAIT    1   0:08  0.00% <httpd>
 1552 www           1  44    0   154M     0K sbwait  0   0:08  0.00% <httpd>
 1575 www           1  44    0   154M 11956K pfault  0   0:08  0.00% httpd
 1570 www           1  44    0   156M 16260K pfault  1   0:08  0.00% httpd
 1583 www           1  44    0   156M 15368K pfault  1   0:08  0.00% httpd
 1580 www           1  44    0   154M 11112K pfault  0   0:08  0.00% httpd
 1600 www           1  44    0   156M  4248K pfault  1   0:08  0.00% httpd
 1589 www           1  44    0   154M     0K sbwait  1   0:08  0.00% <httpd>
 1578 www           1  44    0   154M     0K sbwait  0   0:08  0.00% <httpd>
 1557 www           1  44    0   154M     0K sbwait  1   0:07  0.00% <httpd>
 1617 www           1  44    0   154M 11244K pfault  1   0:07  0.00% httpd
 1574 www           1  44    0   154M  8360K pfault  1   0:07  0.00% httpd
 1560 www           1  44    0   154M 10156K pfault  0   0:07  0.00% httpd
 1603 www           1  44    0   156M  4968K pfault  0   0:07  0.00% httpd
 1590 www           1  44    0   154M 11860K pfault  0   0:07  0.00% httpd
 1592 www           1  44    0   156M 14280K pfault  1   0:07  0.00% httpd
 1581 www           1  44    0   156M  6412K pfault  0   0:07  0.00% httpd
 1586 www           1  44    0   154M 11176K pfault  0   0:07  0.00% httpd
 1608 www           1  44    0   156M  7256K pfault  1   0:07  0.00% httpd
 1568 www           1  44    0   154M 10784K pfault  1   0:07  0.00% httpd
 1591 www           1  44    0   154M 13256K pfault  0   0:07  0.00% httpd
 1610 www           1  44    0   156M  3440K pfault  0   0:07  0.00% httpd
 1650 www           1  44    0   156M     0K sbwait  1   0:07  0.00% <httpd>
 1616 www           1  44    0   154M 13724K pfault  0   0:07  0.00% httpd
 1611 www           1  44    0   154M 10084K pfault  0   0:06  0.00% httpd
 1564 www           1  44    0   154M 12220K pfault  1   0:06  0.00% httpd
 1607 www           1  44    0   156M     0K sbwait  0   0:06  0.00% <httpd>
 1601 www           1  44    0   154M 13728K pfault  1   0:06  0.00% httpd
 1634 www           1  44    0   156M     0K sbwait  0   0:06  0.00% <httpd>
 1606 www           1  44    0   156M     0K sbwait  1   0:06  0.00% <httpd>
 1626 www           1  44    0   156M  3340K pfault  1   0:06  0.00% httpd
 1633 www           1  44    0   156M     0K sbwait  0   0:06  0.00% <httpd>
 1579 www           1  44    0   154M  8508K pfault  1   0:06  0.00% httpd
 1596 www           1  44    0   156M     0K sbwait  1   0:06  0.00% <httpd>
 1584 www           1  44    0   156M  2388K pfault  1   0:06  0.00% httpd
 1641 www           1  44    0   156M  3060K pfault  0   0:06  0.00% httpd
 1632 www           1  44    0   156M  3144K pfault  1   0:06  0.00% httpd
 1657 www           1  44    0   156M     0K sbwait  1   0:06  0.00% <httpd>
 1630 www           1  44    0   156M  6872K pfault  0   0:06  0.00% httpd
 1609 www           1  44    0   156M     0K sbwait  1   0:06  0.00% <httpd>
 1661 www           1  44    0   156M  5688K pfault  0   0:05  0.00% httpd
 1612 www           1  44    0   156M 17816K sbwait  1   0:05  0.00% httpd
 1670 www           1  44    0   156M  4904K pfault  0   0:05  0.00% httpd
 1576 www           1  44    0   154M 13980K pfault  1   0:05  0.00% httpd
 1673 www           1  44    0   156M     0K sbwait  0   0:05  0.00% <httpd>
 1645 www           1  44    0   156M  3312K pfault  0   0:05  0.00% httpd
 1597 www           1  44    0   156M  6004K pfault  1   0:05  0.00% httpd
 1587 www           1  44    0   156M  6008K sbwait  1   0:05  0.00% httpd
 1628 www           1  44    0   156M     0K sbwait  0   0:05  0.00% <httpd>
 1660 www           1  44    0   156M  6180K pfault  0   0:05  0.00% httpd
 1647 www           1  44    0   158M     0K sbwait  1   0:05  0.00% <httpd>
 1582 www           1  44    0   156M     0K sbwait  0   0:05  0.00% <httpd>
 1664 www           1  44    0   156M     0K sbwait  0   0:05  0.00% <httpd>
 1651 www           1  44    0   156M     0K WAIT    1   0:05  0.00% <httpd>
 1674 www           1  44    0   156M  7560K pfault  0   0:05  0.00% httpd
 1631 www           1  44    0   156M  6464K pfault  0   0:05  0.00% httpd
 1655 www           1  44    0   158M     0K sbwait  0   0:05  0.00% <httpd>
 1669 www           1  44    0   156M     0K sbwait  0   0:04  0.00% <httpd>
 1659 www           1  44    0   156M  5936K pfault  1   0:04  0.00% httpd
 1663 www           1  44    0   156M  5828K pfault  0   0:04  0.00% httpd
 1672 www           1  44    0   156M  5764K pfault  0   0:04  0.00% httpd
 1613 www           1  44    0   156M  5784K pfault  1   0:04  0.00% httpd
 1667 www           1  44    0   156M  3696K pfault  1   0:04  0.00% httpd
 1662 www           1  44    0   156M  3336K pfault  0   0:04  0.00% httpd
 1671 www           1  44    0   156M  5036K sbwait  0   0:04  0.00% httpd
 1675 www           1  44    0   156M  6228K pfault  1   0:04  0.00% httpd
 1629 www           1  44    0   156M  5788K pfault  0   0:04  0.00% httpd
```

Is there any way to find what the httpd processes are getting stuck doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, as ETL wrote, enable `mod_status` with `ExtendedStatus On` to see current requests and their states, execution times... etc. You can also use an `apachetop` to get information which file is most popular. If it's not enough information to you, as timmeyh wrote, you can use `strace` but I will suggest `-ff` and `-p` switches (make sure that you specified main apache proccess id).

`-ff` switch

> If the -o filename option is in effect, each processes trace is
>   written to filename.pid where pid is the numeric process id of each
>   process. This is incompatible with -c, since no per-process counts are
>   kept.

`-p` switch

> Attach to the process with the process ID pid and begin tracing. The
>   trace may be terminated at any time by a keyboard interrupt signal
>   (CTRL-C). strace will respond by detaching itself from the traced
>   process(es) leaving it (them) to continue running.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the common strace command to trace what your httpd is doing.
your command would be like the folloing:

`strace -f -o trace.txt /etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd start`

The "-f" strace option traces child processes as they are created by currently traced processes as a result of the 'fork' system call. The -o trace.txt is your outputfile to which you want to dump your trace.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the status module and extended status page to see what are the current requests.